# Selenium: How to stop test sequence?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, if-statement

Using Selenium in Visual Studio. Using NUnit to sort my testcases.

I'm writing a testcase that compares two serialnumbers with a if statement like this:

```
[Test]
public void CompareVariables()
{
   if (string.Equals(serialNumberInfo, serialNumberReport))
      Console.WriteLine($"{serialNumberInfo} and {serialNumberReport} are a match! Proceed!");
   else
      Console.WriteLine($"{serialNumberInfo} and {serialNumberReport} don't match! Cancel test!");
      //method for stopping test missing!
```

I want to be able to abort the rest of the testsequence if the serialnumbers don't match.

Is there a "end/stop test" method or something similar I could put in `else` section?

Comment: What do you mean by abort? Do you mean just stop what it is currently doing and report a failure/pass?

Comment: Yes! Stop the testcase just like visual studio would normally do if it couldn't proceed with a testcase.

Comment: So could you simply throw an exception? That would fail the test and abort the test case

Comment: I'm not familiar with throwing exceptions. How do I write one?

Comment: @JamiePeacock Can I use this: `throw new System.ArgumentException("Serial numbers don't match")`

Comment: That will do it! I left an answer below because I think you either want that or an assertion and I didn't have enough characters in a comment to explain that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a couple of options.

1) simply throw an exception (and fail the test)

Throwing an exception will fail a unit test. There are loads of different types of exceptions but the base is simply `Exception`. You can check the different types of exceptions available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/using-standard-exception-types). Where possible try to pick the exception that most closely represents the error (so bad arguments for example use `ArgumentException` or some derivative there of).

Your test would then look something like this:

```
[Test]
public void CompareVariables()
{
   if (!string.Equals(serialNumberInfo, serialNumberReport))
      throw new Exception($"{serialNumberInfo} and {serialNumberReport} don't match! Cancel test!");

   // The rest of your tests (only run if serialNumberInfo and serialNumberReport) are equal.
}
```

2) Use an assertion (and fail the test)

Unit tests are usually supposed to assert that something desirable happened. If that thing didn't happen then an exception should be thrown (which is often handled for you by some assertion framework).

So you could flip the test to do this:

```
[Test]
public void CompareVariables()
{
   serialNumberInfo.ShouldBe(serialNumberReport);

   // The rest of your tests (only run if serialNumberInfo and serialNumberReport) are equal.
}
```

This is done with [Shouldly](https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly) but there are countless assertion frameworks so pick your favourite. (mstest has one built in but I find it less readable but that is a personal preference).

Note, only use an assertion when you want to explicitly make sure that it should have happened. I.e. This needs to be true for my test to pass, rather than if this happened then abort. That's hard to explain so I hope that makes sense?

Exceptions for when something went wrong, Assertions for when something should have gone right.

3) Leave the test (and pass the test)

If the test exits without an exception being thrown (either manually or via an assertion framework) then the test is considered to be a passing test. Therefor if you wanted to treat this as a pass you could simply return from the test.

```
[Test]
public void CompareVariables()
{
   if (string.Equals(serialNumberInfo, serialNumberReport))
   {
      Console.WriteLine($"{serialNumberInfo} and {serialNumberReport} are a match! Proceed!");
   }
   else
   {
        Console.WriteLine($"{serialNumberInfo} and {serialNumberReport} don't match! Cancel test!");
        return;
   }

   // The rest of your tests
```

}

This will mark the test as passing, but mean the rest of the operations in the test are not run. I would try not to do this however - unless you really understand why you want this because you could start passing tests without knowing why they passed (i.e. without asserting anything)

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to end the test early without failing it, simply use return.

```
[Test]
public void MyTest() {

    //Do some stuff
    if(!shouldContinue) {

        return;

    }

}
```

I do this reasonably often given certain conditions may warrant additional assertions, and other conditions may not. Throwing an exception will fail the test. This will not fail it.

Edit: I just noticed that the other responder mentioned this at the end of their answer. So ignore me :)

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution. I used Assert.Fail() with a message. This stopped the test execution and logs a message.

I'm using C# with Selenium.

```
If (condition is true) 
{ // execute code }
else 
{ Assert.Fail("Condition was false."); } // stops test.
```